# How to model a 1:1 association as class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

ASP.NET MVC and I got an issue that I don't know how to solve

I have a Vehicle class in model

```
VehicleId
Register
.... Etc
```

And a Driver class

```
DriverId
FirstName 
LastName
```

I want to create a new table in order to control of what vehicle have a Driver where each Vehicle cannot have more than one Driver

I think of creating a table DriverVehicle with the key from Vehicle and Driver.  Any help related with this would be a big help. I am working with ASP.NET MVC and EF.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a mutually optional 1:1 association between independent entities (more exactly: 0..1-0..1). As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22237880/861716), EF isn't really helpful here, but there are some options.

The first option is to settle with a 1-0..1 association, which is fully supported by EF. But either `Car` or `Driver` should have a primary key that's [also a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26425364/861716) to the other entity. From what I read, this is not what you want. You want both entities to be able to exist independent of the other.

So the only option is, as you describe, introducing a third entity, aka a *junction class*. Now, Entity Framework only supports this for many-to-many associations, not for 1:1. So you'll have to map the association as many-to-many, but take some special measures to prevent duplicate associations on both ends.

To achieve that, this is what I came up with:

```
public class Car
{
    public Car()
    {
        CarDrivers = new HashSet<CarDriver>();
    }
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CarDriver> CarDrivers { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public Driver()
    {
        CarDrivers = new HashSet<CarDriver>();
    }
    public int DriverId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CarDriver> CarDrivers { get; set; }
}

public class CarDriver
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int DriverId { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
}
```

This is an explicit many-to-many association (i.e. having a visible junction class), but restricted to 1 at both ends by the unique indexes on both foreign keys in `CarDriver`.

So at least at the database side, the proper multiplicity of the association is enforced. However, in your code, nothing stops you from adding more than one `CarDriver` to the `CarDrivers` collections. This will throw an ugly database constraint error, so you'll have to guard this with custom validation.

Answer (score 0):

Add DriverId as a foreign column in Vehicle table and add virtual list of Vehicles for a driver. So each vehicle will have single driver and each driver can drive many vehicles.

Vehicle Class

```
public virtual Driver Driver { get;set; }
public virtual int DriverId { get;set; }    //make it null if you think some vechile dont have driver
```

Driver Class

```
public virtual IList<Vehicle> Vehicles { get;set; }
```