# One sided one-to-one relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, one-to-one

I have two model classes (`Tickets` and `Activities`), where `Activities` is more like a look-up table, and is not suppose to hold any navigational properties or FK's of other entities.

A record in `Tickets` is supposed to have a single `Activity`, but in the whole table of `Tickets`, there will be many of the same `Activities`. Activities needs to be a table, and not (for example) an enum, because of the possibility of future updates and amendments.

Although this seems trivial enough, I keep encountering errors like `Identity is Set to off`.

My models:

```
public class Tickets
{
    public int ID {get; set;}

    // fk
    public int ActivityID {get; set;

    // nav property
    public Activity Activity {get; set;}
    // other properties.        
}

public class Activity
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int RankOrder {get; set;}
    //other properties
}
```

I have specified a domainmapping for the `Tickets` model:

```
    builder.HasOne(t => t.Activity)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.ActivityID);
```

based on this SO-post and blogpost: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889367/is-it-possible-to-capture-a-0-1-to-0-1-relationship-in-entity-framework) and [here](https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-setup-entity-framework-code-first-to-have-only-one-side-0-to-1-relationship) but I don't get it to work, my most recent error message is:

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Activity' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Also, with this mapping it seems that EF created a Ticket column in the Activity table, something that I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
builder.Entity<Ticket>() 
         .HasOne(t => t.Activity)
        .WithMany(a => a.Ticket)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.ActivityID);
```

Comment: my Activity table doesn't have any navigational properties. So `.WithMany( a => a.Ticket)` isn't possible. I changed my code to make it more clear, maybe the `string Activity` was seen as a nav prop.